# Producer/consumer with asyncio tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

As an exercise, I tried implementing a minimal *producer-consumer* scenario using `asyncio` instead of threads.

```py
import asyncio

from queue import Queue

async def producer(queue, n):
    for i in range(n):
        item = f"item-{i}"
        queue.put(item)
        print(f"[producer] Produced {item}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    queue.put(None)
    print("[producer] Done producing")

async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        if not item:
            break
        print(f"[consumer] Consumed {item}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print("[consumer] No more items to consume")

async def main():
    queue = Queue()
    prod_task = asyncio.create_task(producer(queue, 5))
    cons_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))
    await prod_task
    await cons_task

asyncio.run(main())
```

The code works as expected. The wait in `consumer` is needed to give the `producer` time to place another item on the queue so that the next call to `get` succeeds.

Based on that, I decided to try and use [`queue.get`'s `timeout` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get) instead.

```py
async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get(timeout=0.5)
        if not item:
            break
        print(f"[consumer] Consumed {item}")
    print("[consumer] No more items to consume")
```

I expected the updated code to behave the same as the original but, instead, it looks like the `consumer` is suspended indefinitely and the `producer` runs to its completion, when an `Empty` queue exception is raised.

I'm pretty sure I've either misinterpreted the documentation or missed some other detail on task scheduling. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

1. Why is my expectation wrong that using `timeout` in the call to `get` should be equivalent to `sleep`ing?
2. Even though the original code worked, having to manually sync the times feels a little fragile; what would a more robust solution (assuming async concurrency) look like?

Thank you!

Comment: You should use `asyncio.Queue` instead of `queue.Queue`.

Comment: @dirn That was... it. :) Thank you. As a bonus, by using asyncio.Queue, manual sync-ing in no longer necessary.